# Infrared cutoff in the Kramers-Kronig relation for the marginal Fermi liquid

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, fermi-liquids, self-energy

I am going through Andre-Marie Tremblay's derivation of the real part of the self energy in his lecture notes on [the many-body problem](https://www.physique.usherbrooke.ca/tremblay/cours/phy-892/N-corps.pdf). On page
254, if we take the imaginary $\Sigma''(k,\,\omega)\sim \omega'^2$, then the real part $\Sigma'(k,\,\omega)$ can be found from the following:

\begin{align}
\lim_{\omega\rightarrow \textrm{small}}\left\{
\Sigma'(k,\,\omega)-\Sigma'(k,\,\infty)
\right\}&=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow \textrm{small}} P\int\frac{d\omega'}{\pi}\frac{\Sigma''(k,\,\omega')}{\omega'-\omega}\notag\\
&=P\int \frac{d\omega'}{\pi} \omega'+\omega P\int \frac{d\omega'}{\pi}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}\Sigma'(k,\,\omega)\bigg|_{\omega=0}=P\int \frac{d\omega'}{\pi}$$

Because the integral is taken with certain cutoffs in the integrals, $\Sigma'(k,\,\omega)\sim \omega$.

My confusion when studying the [marginal Fermi liquid](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.1996). Because $\Sigma''(k,\,\omega)\sim \omega$, the authors state that $\Sigma'(k,\omega)\sim \omega \log (\omega/\omega_c)$, where $\omega_c$ is the ultraviolet cutoff. Repeating the above calculation for a linear relationship for $\Sigma''(k,\,\omega)$, we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}\Sigma'(k,\,\omega)\bigg|_{\omega=0}=P\int\frac{d\omega'}{\pi \omega'}$$

For the regular Fermi liquid result, the limits were the infrared and ultraviolet cutoffs, while here the lower limit is $\omega$. If we assume this for the regular Fermi liquid, then $\Sigma'(k,\,\omega)\sim \omega^2$, which is incorrect. **So why, for the marginal Fermi liquid, do we take different integration limits in the Kramers-Kronig relation than for the regular Fermi liquid?** Any explanation why (or explanation of any mistake I made) would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Specifically, why can't we just take the infrared cutoff for the marginal Fermi liquid to be some $\omega_i>0$? Why is the ultraviolet cutoff some constant but the infrared $\omega$, and why in the regular Fermi liquid case are both cutoffs arbitrary?